# How can I view Facebook chat history?

Tags: facebook, chat

I wonder if Facebook stores its chat history anywhere or if there is a way to enable chat history. Do you know a way to get the chat history?

I have tried with:

```
javascript:buddyList.itemOnClick(_ID);
```

it opens the chat window for the user, but it doesn't show any history.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It doesn't.

> **How do I delete or look through my Chat History? Is it saved permanently?**
>   You can view recent conversation history by opening a chat window with your friend. At this time, *you cannot view older conversations or conversations with friends who are not currently online*.

(emphasis added by me)
From here: http://www.facebook.com/help/?faq=12886

However, you can use some browser add-ons or extensions. You can find a tutorial here: http://www.neurosoftware.ro/programming-blog/facebook-web-design/tutorial/how-to-save-your-complete-facebook-chat-history/