# Is there a way to retrieve/search through old Facebook chat messages?

Tags: facebook, facebook-messenger

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I view Facebook chat history?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/6223/how-can-i-view-facebook-chat-history)

I assume that chat messages are stored on the FB servers, but I cannot seem to find a way to access them en-masse through the FB interface.

Is there a method for doing this (or a tool available for the job)?

Comment: The "duplicate" mark does not answer my question. I do not see in that question any method for, en-masse, retrieve and search through my facebook chat message history.

Comment: The only way I see a difference is that you are talking about Facebook messages (within the message inbox) and not Facebook Chat then you should update your question to better reflect what you are trying to achieve. Otherwise both questions come to the same ends which is there is no way to access chat history via interface or api calls.

Comment: Cool - I see the duplication now. Thanks!